# Excel 2007 user warning when opening xls files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, xml

I am getting the following error warning when opening an .xls file generated using 'CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.dll' in Excel 2007:

> The file you are trying to open,`''`, is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/66195/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the .xls file (Microsoft Excel 97-2003 format) is actually an .xlsx file (Microsoft Excel 2007 format). Changing the file extension from .xls to .xlsx should clear the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

In your VBA code, use this command:

> Application.DisplayAlerts = False

this will suppress any such warnings.

Answer (score -1):

It's xml spreadsheet 2003 format, the correct extension is xml which is why it does not need excel installed.

Comment: I think you meant to say `.xlsx`, not `.xml`?

Answer (score -1):

I tried changing the file extension to several extensions -- but the error always came up.  I tried changing the settings in the registry -- but the error still appeared (I do not have admin rights and group policy probably overrides). I added [Application.DisplayAlerts = False] to my macro and it works!