# How do I suppress the "file format and extension of MyFile.csv" do not match."?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I'm opening a lot of csv files using Excel recently and am repeatedly receiving the warning:-

> The file format and extension of MyFile.csv do not match. The file
>   could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, do not open
>   it. Do you want to open it anyway?

Is there any way to suppress this warning?

I have looked at the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/66195/is-there-any-way-to-suppress-the-excel-2007-warning-in-a-different-format-than), but can't find anything like that in the registry. This is Windows 8, and Excel 2013 (15.0.4719.1000).

Comment: Can you show us the contents of one of these CSVs (at least the first few lines)? As for the version, come on... is it not mentioned in the Start Screen item or in Excel's splash screen? Also look under File > Help.

Comment: @Karan, the files are actually `.xls` files so don't print very nicely. Why they are called `.csv` I don't know.

Comment: So can't you rename them all to .XLS before opening? Also, found the version of Excel?

Comment: A CSV file is not xls so that is odd... How do you know they are .xls files?

Comment: @Dave: He must have tried editing them in a text editor perhaps, or maybe he just knows what they are but not why they're named that way. My guess would be some dumb automated tool/online service is generating these XLS-turned-CSV files, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Karan, you are right about the source of the CSV files. I have edited the Excel version into the question. While looking for this, I also happened upon the "trust center", but nothing in there seems clear this warning (it can be used to clear a lot of other pointless warnings, though).

Comment: Ok, so... again, isn't renaming them all to .XLS before opening an option?

Comment: @Karan, it is for the time being, and I will do so, but I'm looking forward to receiving a lot more of these in future. Still, if it has to be done, it has to be done. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well I'll still recommend renaming as it's the simplest solution that gets the job done, and that's always best rather than messing with the registry and stuff unnecessarily. You can always create a batch file to do the renaming for you (simple `ren *.csv *.xls`) that you can double-click and voilà. If you absolutely must leave them as CSV however, try creating *ExtensionHardening* as mentioned in that answer you linked to under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security` (Office 2013 = 15.0). I have no idea if it still works with this version though.

Answer (score 4):

Having looked at [this article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/how-to-change-the-way-excel-scans-a-textcsv-file/24741ea7-5490-4d9a-a6b0-7728098330a2?auth=1) there is an issue with having the first column called 'ID'. You can rename this column to anything else including 'id', or reorder the columns such that the ID column is not first.

I appreciate that this does not help with the bunch of csv files you have already created though.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question.

Comment: Related: [How to generate .csv file for Excel without error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31607780/3357935)